# Rails could not find gem

Tags: ruby, gem

So if I try to start my server I get the error

```
Could not find abstract-1.0.0 in any of the sources
Try running bundle install.
```

I run that and I get

```
Using abstract (1.0.0)
```

I also have the gem listed in my GemFile

Furthermore running a bundle show abstract gives me the correct path for the gem. That path is also referenced in gem env.

Comment: I'm running into this same problem.  Did you ever solve it?